# Understanding Monte Carlo Simulation with Stratified Sampling

Tags: monte-carlo

I am studying Monte Carlo Simulation with Stratified Sampling following [Martin Haugh's lectures notes](https://martin-haugh.github.io/files/MonteCarlo/MCS_Var_Red_Advanced.pdf). As is it explained the variance of the estimator is
$$
Var(\hat{\theta}_{st,n}) = \sum_{j=1}^{m} \frac{p_{j}\sigma_{j}^2}{n_{j}}
$$
At the footnote of page 12 he specifies that $$Var(\hat{\theta}_{st,n})= \sum_{j=1}^{m} Var ( \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n_{j}} Y_{i}^{(j)}}{n_{j}})p_{j}^2 $$ and that this quantity can be estimated using both $ sum_{j}=\sum_{i=1}^{n_{j}} Y_{i}^{(j)}  $  and $ sumsquares_{j}= \sum_{i=1}^{n_{j}} Y_{i}^{(j)^2}  $ . I do not get how this can be done considering the fact that later in the page's 13 algorithm the estimator used is  is
$\hat{\sigma}_{j}^2 = (sumsquares_{j} - \frac{sum_{j}^2}{n_{j}})/ (n_{j}-1)$

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you be a little more specific about your concern? The line of code $\hat{\sigma}_{j}^2 = (sumsquares_{j} - \frac{sum_{j}^2}{n_{j}})/ (n_{j}-1)$ appears to be calculating the variance of $\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n_{j}} Y_{i}^{(j)}}{n_{j}}$ as required in the footnote.

Comment: Precisely that. Where does that the  expresion $ \hat{\sigma}_{j}^{2}$ come from and how is that is equivalent to the variance of  $ \frac{ \sum_{i=1}^{n_{j}} Y_{i}^{(j)} } {n_{j}} $